# How do I integrate a website template on my main wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress website made to show a portfolio of websites, so the client can have an idea about what kind of wordpress-based website I can create for them.

My question is, is there any smart way of creating a live website template inside a website? My approach would be to install another wordpress release into a folder (e.g domain.com/template1; /template2 etc.) but it feels kind of...ancient.

Is there any other way or am I steering into the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I would say, the easiest way is to make a second customize.php, because there you have the possibility to take a live preview and make a new site template with it.

Important: Do not forget to restrict a lot of settings like, choose this Template - otherwise it will be set as default for your website :)